# Execute vector of futures in parallel with the supplied number of threads

Tags: rust, async-await, future

I'm new to Rust and have the following issue.

I have a vector of `std::Future` and due to some weird requirements I have to create a new thread pool every time the futures are executed. Like the following:

```
fn execute_in_parallel(futs: Vec<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), SomeError>> + Send>>>, threads_nums: u32) -> Vec<Result<(), SomeError>>{
    //create threads_nums threads and execute all the futures with them
}
```

I tried [`futures`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) crate and its [`join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) function, but it does not seem to create any threads any time it is called.

Is there a way to do it? Maybe tokio would be helpful here.

Comment: What "weird requirements" do you have?

Comment: `join_all` would really do the opposite of what you're looking for, it's creating a single future which groups up the others *and drives them*, so every time the JoinFuture is polled it checks and polls the joined futures internally. Tokio (or some other executor) is probably what you're looking for indeed, you probably want to `spawn` each future, then you can regulate the concurrency via runtime configuration (spawning an OS thread per future seems... not ideal).

Comment: Although you may not experience any gain depending on the source of the future e.g. a tokio `JoinHandle` (the result of `spawn`) is it self a `Future`. spawning that into a separate task will have no useful effect.

Comment: You should be able to create a [`futures::executor::ThreadPool`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/executor/struct.ThreadPool.html) and then use `spawn_obj_ok()` to schedule all passed futures on the threadpool. Further details depend on if you want your fn to block until completion, etc.